# Word2Vec Wordvectors Most similar

Tags: word2vec

I trained a Word2Vec Model an I am trying formulate the most_similar function mathematicaly. 
I thought about a set, that contains the n most similar word, given a word as reference.

Exist there somewhere a good definition?

Answer (score 0):

You can view the source code which implements `most_similar()` for the `gensim` Python library's `KeyedVectors` abstraction (for holding & performing common actions on sets of word-vectors):

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/fbc7d0952f1461fb5de3f6423318ae33d87524e3/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py#L491

Roughly, it first computes a target vector – by combining any `positive` & `negative` examples the caller has provided. In the common case, this might just be a single ('positive') word-vector.

Then, it calculates the cosine-similarity with every other vector, and sorts those similarities for highest, and returns the top-N results.